# sbt release generates from folder structure in maven central

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

I'm trying to release a [library](https://github.com/otto-de/jetty-ldap) via sonatype to maven-central.
When releasing via `sbt +release` I successfully upload the jar.
But the folder structure is wrong:
`https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/otto/jetty-ldap_2.10_0.13/0.1.1/` 
There is the sbt version in the path (0.13).

With this structure I am not able to use the jar as a dependency. I use it like this: 
`libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "de.otto" %% "jetty-ldap" % "0.1.1")`

An error occurs:

> tried
>   [warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/otto/jetty-ldap_2.11/0.1.1/jetty-ldap_2.11-0.1.1.pom

The paths obviously don't match.
Does someone have any ideas? I am kinda lost here..

My build.sbt shortened:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
settings(
    name := "jetty-ldap",
    organization := "de.otto",
    licenses := Seq("Apache License, Version 2.0" -> url("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt")),

    homepage := Some(url("https://dev.otto.de/")),
    sbtPlugin := true
)
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.12.5"
publishMavenStyle := true
publishArtifact in Test := false
pomIncludeRepository := { _ => false }
publishTo := {
    val nexus = "https://oss.sonatype.org/"
    if (version.value.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")) {
        Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
    } else {
        Some("releases" at nexus + "service/local/staging/deploy/maven2")
    }
}

crossSbtVersions := Vector("0.13.17", "1.1.0")

// From: https://github.com/xerial/sbt-sonatype#using-with-sbt-release-plugin
import sbtrelease.ReleasePlugin.autoImport.ReleaseTransformations._
releaseCrossBuild := true
releaseProcess := Seq[ReleaseStep](
    checkSnapshotDependencies,
    inquireVersions,
    runClean,
    releaseStepCommandAndRemaining("^ test"),
    setReleaseVersion,
    commitReleaseVersion,
    tagRelease,
    releaseStepCommandAndRemaining("^ publishSigned"),
    setNextVersion,
    commitNextVersion,
    releaseStepCommand("sonatypeReleaseAll"),
    pushChanges
)
```

**Solution by [evgeny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546520/evgeny)**

To resolve the issue, we had to remove the line `sbtPlugin := true` since this results in an sbt-version in the folder-structure.

Comment: `sbtPlugin := true` you publish sbt plugin, right? Sbt plugin is published with sbt version in apth.

Comment: YES. Thank you. I totally overlooked that. :)

Comment: @Evgeny I just realized that this question is still "unanswered".
Could you post your comment as an answer since it was the correct fix? :)

Comment: Jiust did it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sbtPlugin := true` you publish sbt plugin, right?

Sbt plugin is published with sbt version in path